# Implement asnyc method inside a Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2017 . I need to implement async method inside thread .

Event which starting the thread

```
   public void btnAction_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var load = new System.Threading.Thread((t) =>
        {
           ShowWarning();

        });
        load.Start(btnText);

    }
```

async method should implement inside the thread

```
 private async void ShowWarning()
 {
       bool response = await  DisplayAlert("Warning", "Please Enter
                            The Key","Yes","No");
 }
```

Comment: `async void` is only meant for event handlers. Why use a thread at all?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What does it mean to "implement a task *in* a thread"?

Comment: Inside that method there is another part of function as well (not mentioned it in here ) that's why i put it inside a thread

Answer (score 3):

If `DisplayAlert` is truely *asynchronous*, why do you start a thread at all? You can declare your event handler `async` and simply awiat `ShowWarning`:

```
public async void btnAction_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await ShowWarning();
}
```

You might want to disable `btnAction` before the `await` and re-enable it after the `await` again, so you avoid another click event while awaiting.

---

And note that it's bad practice to declare `ShowWarning` as `async void`. It should be

```
private async Task ShowWarning()
{ ... }
```

(In case of the button event handler it's ok to return `async void` because otherwise you couldn't assign it to an event).

---

If you really need to run `ShowWarning` on a different thread, you can use `Task.Run()`:

```
public async void btnAction_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(ShowWarning);
}
```

Comment: Inside that method there is another part of function as well (not mentioned it in here ) that's why i put it inside a thread

Comment: @charitht99perera Thatswhy you should post the **relevant** code in your question. I updated the answer.

Comment: sorry for that , I removed it since it may be confusing